# Dynamically change viewport with jquery based on width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport, meta

I have 2 viewports that I want to use.  The site is built responsive across a range of breakpoints, but on some pages we really just want to display the full desktop view UNLESS it's a phone, then we want the responsive to kick in.

So, on desktops, tablets and everything in between, we want this viewport that doesn't really respond.  It just scales the desktop page to fit the screen.  When I manually set it to this, everything works great on desktop/tablets.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

On mobile (let's say under 768 pixels), we want the viewport below.  When I manually set it to this, everthing works great on mobile.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

The trick then, is how do I nake these viewports dynamically change based on width?

I've tried to get something going that looks like this, but it's not working.  I suspect due to some flaws in my javascript.  When testing on a phone I'm still getting the 'desktop' view.

```
// first set the viewport to the desktop settings
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0" />

// then some javascript to dynamically change
<script>
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
    mvp.setAttribute('content','width=device-width');
    mvp.setAttribute('content','initial-scale=1.0');
}
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

As always, thanks in advance....

Comment: It's a tricky one. I am working on a script to do that kind of thing reliably on all browsers, which requires to set the viewport twice to avoid zooming issues... ATM, the issue with your code is that window.innerWidth is based on the default viewport (usually 960 or 980). Unless you set the viewport at `width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0` first (with both set). window.innerWidth is not going to be accurate. Here is more info on the quirks with viewport: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/01/widthdevicewidt.html